# date() or format_date() returning 1970?

Tags: php, date

I have a table with a date field, which is correctly populated.
When I do the following `<?php print $mytable->date; ?>` works fine; however, when I format it with `date()` or `format_date()` it just returns 01/01/1970.

It's stored in an array before being put into an HTML table if that makes a difference.

Comment: show us the line with the date function your using: date("F j, Y, g:i a",UNIX_TIMESTAMP);

Comment: What is the value of $mytable->date when you print it out?

Comment: If it outputs 1-1-1970 than that column (or result expression) contained a zero (or not even an integer).

Comment: @mario or it wasn't a timestamp

Comment: All I'm doing is date('d/m/Y', $mytable->date), the value of $mytable->date is a timestamp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the following (if the format of `$mytable->date` fits strtotime()) and adopt first parameter to your needs:

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $mytable->date )); ?>
```